# Does Adding or Removing Search Engines in TB's Search Bar Affect Annonymity?

Tags: deanonymization, add-on

Suppose I add or remove a search engine from Tor Browser's search bar; will my anonymity be compromised?

I've tried to research this by running Panopticlick before and after installing a search engine.  Although my Panopticlick "score" (number of bits of identifying information) seems vary a bit every time I run it, even with no changes at all to the browser (the uniqueness of my screen-size-and-color-depth setting changes by a few hundredths of a bit each time, even if I don't alter the setting at all), I see no consistent change in score before and after installing an engine.

This holds regardless of whether installation of the engine entails installing an actual add-on, as, for example, the S3.Google Translator does.  So I conclude that Panopticlick probably is not capable of answering my question.

In the same vein, does adding bookmarks to my TB compromise anonymity?  What about changing a setting, such as the name or location of the download directory?